# Python pandas to partially collapse 2d matrix

Tags: python, grouping, pivot-table, pandas, crosstab

I would like to partially "collapse" a `DataFrame`/matrix and keep the  structure intact by just summing the condensed values.  For example, I have this:

```
CHROM     POS     GENE     DESC     JOE      FRED   BILLY    SUSAN    TONY
10        1442    LOXL4    bad      1        0      0        1        0
10        335     LOXL4    bad      1        0      0        0        0
10        3438    LOXL4    good     0        0      1        0        0
10        4819    PYROXD2  bad      0        1      0        0        0
10        4829    PYROXD2  bad      0        1      0        1        0
10        9851    HPS1     good     1        0      0        0        0
```

The first 4 columns are descriptors, and the last 4 columns are people/observations.  The end goal is to count how many total "good" and "bad" observations per GENE per person.  Thus, I want this:

```
GENE     DESC     JOE      FRED   BILLY    SUSAN    TONY
LOXL4    bad      2        0      0        1        0
LOXL4    good     0        0      1        0        0
PYROXD2  bad      0        2      0        1        0
HPS1     good     1        0      0        0        0
```

The following code collapses all the individual observations (Joe, Fred, etc), how can I keep them separate?  I would also like to be flexible enough to accommodate a more individuals in the future (keeping the same 4 descriptor columns)

```
mytable.groupby(['GENE','DESC']).size()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the aggregate method of the groupby object:

```
In [156]: df
Out[156]: 
   CHROM   POS     GENE  DESC  JOE  FRED  BILLY  SUSAN  TONY
0     10  1442    LOXL4   bad    1     0      0      1     0
1     10   335    LOXL4   bad    1     0      0      0     0
2     10  3438    LOXL4  good    0     0      1      0     0
3     10  4819  PYROXD2   bad    0     1      0      0     0
4     10  4829  PYROXD2   bad    0     1      0      1     0
5     10  9851     HPS1  good    1     0      0      0     0

In [157]: grouped = df.groupby(['GENE', 'DESC'])

In [158]: grouped.agg(np.sum) # agg is a shortcut for aggregate
Out[158]: 
              CHROM   POS  JOE  FRED  BILLY  SUSAN  TONY
GENE    DESC                                            
HPS1    good     10  9851    1     0      0      0     0
LOXL4   bad      20  1777    2     0      0      1     0
        good     10  3438    0     0      1      0     0
PYROXD2 bad      20  9648    0     2      0      1     0
```

As mentioned by Daniel Velkow in the comment, the groupby object has some "build in" methods for simple aggregations like `sum`, `mean`, ... (something like `ufuncs` in numpy which are available as methods for numpy arrays). So the last step could be further simplified to

```
In [159]: grouped.sum()
Out[159]: 
              CHROM   POS  JOE  FRED  BILLY  SUSAN  TONY
GENE    DESC                                            
HPS1    good     10  9851    1     0      0      0     0
LOXL4   bad      20  1777    2     0      0      1     0
        good     10  3438    0     0      1      0     0
PYROXD2 bad      20  9648    0     2      0      1     0
```

If you want different operations on each column, according to the [docs](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns) you can pass a `dict` to `aggregate`.

However I found no way to specify a function for a single column and use a default for others. So one way would be to define a custom aggregation function:

```
def custom_agg(s, default=np.sum, other={}):
    if s.name in other.keys():
        return other[s.name](s)
    else:
        return default(s)
```

and than apply it by passing the function and the args to `agg`:

```
In [59]: grouped.agg(custom_agg, default=np.sum, other={'CHROM': np.mean})
Out[59]: 
              CHROM   POS  JOE  FRED  BILLY  SUSAN  TONY
GENE    DESC                                            
HPS1    good     10  9851    1     0      0      0     0
LOXL4   bad      10  1777    2     0      0      1     0
        good     10  3438    0     0      1      0     0
PYROXD2 bad      10  9648    0     2      0      1     0
```

Comment: Also `grouped.sum()` is a shorthand for `grouped.agg(np.sum)`

Comment: As a followup question, can you perform different operations on each column when aggregating?  For example if I wanted to sum the last 5 columns as given, but take the average of the "CHROM" column instead of summing those values?

Comment: @alexhli I updated my answer. Usually passing a dict would be enough, but you must name all columns. If you want a default for the rest of the columns, I think you need a custom function.